# Using POST to get Twitter followers

Tags: php, twitter

I have written the following codes which retrieves twitter followers, more than 100, for a particular user.

```
<?php
$cursor = -1;
$account_from = 'twitterapi';
do
{
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor='.$cursor.'&screen_name='.$account_from.'');

$accounts = json_decode($json);


foreach ($accounts->ids as $account)
{

        $a[] = $account ; 


}
$cursor = $accounts->next_cursor;


}
while ($cursor > 0);


    $n = ceil(count($a) / 100) ; 
    $b = array_chunk($a, 100) ; 


    for($i=0 ; $i<$n ; $i++) {

        $user = ''; 

        for($j=0 ; $j<count($b[$i]) ; $j++) {

                    $user =  $user.$b[$i][$j].',' ;


        }

        $json=file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id='.$user.'') ;
        $fo= json_decode($json);

        foreach ($fo as $key => $jsons) {

             foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {

                     if($key == 'screen_name'){

                             $arr[] = $value;

                    }

            }

        }

    }

    return $arr ; 



?>
```

But as you can see, there are too many bottlenecks in the HTTP requests and sometimes if the user has many followers the script will timeout due to PHP's maximum execution limit.

However according to [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup), we should use POST for larger requests. I am not sure how can i use POST instead.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cURL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Set CURLOPT_POST as TRUE in [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). There are examples in the Examples section of the page

Answer (score 0):

Using file_get_contents, you can't send a POST request. I recommend using [Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org), which is essentially a clean OOP wrapper around cURL. There's even an example for the Twitter API on the 'tour' page: [here](http://guzzlephp.org/tour/http.html)

Comment: You can send POST requests using file_get_contents: `file_get_contents($url, NULL, stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'POST', 'content' => http_build_query($data)))))`

Comment: @AlfEaton Yeah, I must have been having a brain-fart whilst writing this answer.